# What to show proof of accommodation for visa if you have an email rent agreement?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, spain, proof-of-accommodation

I will be traveling to Spain as a collaborator in an research institute. While looking for accommodation, I have found a person willing to rent a room to me for almost 3 months (less than 90 days). I have had email correspondence with him on this matter.

So, what do I show as Proof of accommodation in my visa application? Is it feasible/possible to sign some kind of agreement with the host and will that be accepted as proof of accommodation

Comment: Can your host research institution provide an additional proof on their letterhead with a seal or some such?  I assume this is a short stay visa instead of a one year long stay visa.

Comment: It is a short stay and my host institute is sending me an internship agreement, but they are not the ones providing me with accommodation. I am looking for accommodation privately

Comment: Does your research institute have an international office?  If so, contact them.  I worked in France on a long stay visa.  Granted, it is a different visa than "short stay" but my host institution's international office included in their paperwork that I would be looking for accommodation privately.

Answer (score 1):

You would likely need more than an email as proof accommodation, as part of the visa application to Spain (consistent with Schengen visa guidance).

A letter of invitation outlining the fee-based agreement would be more suitable, the person renting to you should be a citizen or a legal resident Spain, the document verified at the local police station. It should have:

- Name of the individual (landlord or sublessor)
- His/her contact details (address, telephone, email)
- Address of the rented unit
- Rental period (entry and exit dates)
- Indication that the unit (house/apartment/room) is a legal rental (i.e., registered with appropriate authorities)
- Signature of landlord and renter

Attach the original, signed letter to your application.